# Writing own custome syscall/int 0x80 on x64 system

Tags: assembly, linux, x86-64

Is there a way to write my own `syscall`/`int 0x80` without using them?
So, normally it goes like

```
setup registers
...
syscall or int 0x80
```

and I am interested in doing this without `syscall`/`int 0x80`

```
setup registers
call mysyscall
```

where can I find implementation of `syscall` or `int 0x80`? Or is it too low level to implement it in asm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TL;DR:* These are two instructions supported *by* the CPU, you cannot implement them in assembly, as they are (or aren't) part of the assembly language you're using.

*Some more background:*

An interrupt (the assembly [`int`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_142.html) instruction is causing a software interrupt) is a special event for the CPU. The CPU immediately (This is slightly inaccurate as advanced performance optimizations and low-level features are ignored for the sake of simplicity) stops executing the instruction sequence it was executing, saves the context of the current execution (such as the `EIP` and other control registers, most not directly accessible to the user), and switches to a specifically designated code sequence that is in charge of handling that specific interrupt.

Examples of hardware interrupts are related to handling power, hard-disk network and other peripherals, as well as when a program fails accessing a memory region, fails with certain calculations (divide by zero), floating point errors, tries executing a privileged or an invalid instruction and many others.

Additionally, a program can intentionally trigger an interrupt by using the `int` instruction which receives a single operand - the interrupt id to trigger.

When an interrupt happens, the resumes execution at the address pointed by the interrupt index in the [Interrupt Descriptor Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table) (aka Interrupt Vector Table), in the case of `int 0x80`, that's the address at offset `0x80`, obviously.

As interrupts are an expensive operation for the CPU (it entails a lot of bookkeeping related to theads and context switches, among other things), AMD (and later Intel) introduced the [`sysenter`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_313.html) instruction (called `syscall` by Intel). That instruction keeps bookkeeping to the minimum by only raising to ring0 and executing kernel code.